# Executing Maven task from shell script and getting error codes

Tags: bash, shell, maven

I'm executing a Maven deploy task from a bash script however even if the Maven task fails the script will continue and complete without errors.

I have tried the -e flag but that causes the deploy to fail. I also tried the following (pseudo code)

```
result_code= mvn deploy
if [$result_code -gt 0];then
exit 1
```

Any suggestions how i can identify if the deploy was successful?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`result_code=mvn deploy` is not the way to get return status

you can try e.g. :

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn deploy
STATUS=$?
if [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Deployment Successful"
else
echo "Deployment Failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition if anyone using Windows 10, here is the example which I use:

```
mvn deploy
if not %ERROR_CODE%==0 goto error

echo SUCCESS
goto end

:error
echo FAILED

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one other possible reason a person's mvn task may return 0 despite failing: **be careful about piping the output of maven to other programs**. For example, I'm using `grcat` (which `grc` is build on top of), which will always return exit code 0;

```
\mvn compile | grcat ~/conf.mvn
```

I'm not sure how to retain my nice color coding of the output. There is color_maven.sh out there but that has other issues.

Comment: If you run mvn in bash, you can access the exit status of each command in the pipeline using the PIPESTATUS array variable provided by bash: `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` will give the exit code of the `mvn compile` command and `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` will give the exit code of the `grcat ~/conf.mvn` command.