# Bash script -- Using expect to read from Standard Output

Tags: java, bash, maven, expect

I have a java program that is known to be functional. I am trying wrap a bash script around it to pass in each index in the associative array as a parameter. When the java program is run, Maven writes output to the console.

What I want is for bash to wait to see the line "[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS" in the standard output before moving on. Once it has that confirmation that the java process ran successfully, I perform some tasks on the text file the java program created. Only then do I want to go to the next iteration of the loop.

I have an associative array of parameters:

```
params=([1]cat [2]dog [3]fish)
```

Loop logic:

```
for i in "${!params[@]}"
do
    mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.ProgramMainClass" -Dexec.args="$i '2015-11-01'" | /usr/bin/expect "[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS"
    mv /tmp/outputfile.csv /path/to/directory/${params[$i]}_outputfile.csv
done
```

I cannot figure out the syntax to make expect work on standard output. I've read several examples and pawed through the expect manual, but I'm just not understanding how it works.

I feel like I should be able to pipe standard output to expect and have the script wait until expect sees the given string. But it's not working. Any advise? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need expect to expect an `[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS`. Pure bash (or maybe `grep`) is more than capable. E.g., `blah blah command | grep -q '^\[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS$'`, and check for return status.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377436/executing-maven-task-from-shell-script-and-getting-error-codes

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
expect "*\\\[INFO\\\] BUILD SUCCESS*"
```

The triple backslashes are needed for [square bracket protection in Tcl](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1403_Square-Bracket-protection-in-Tcl.html).